# Выложить проект на Vue.js на веб - сервер

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

Здравствуйте, изучаю Vue.js. Устанавливаю его через vue-cli с помощью webpack.
На выходе, после разработки, получается вот такая иерархия файлов: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать дальше? Какие файлы здесь нужны, а какие удалить и выложить на веб сервер? Спасибо)

Comment: Вы уже вызывали в консоли команду `npm build`?

Comment: @Bleser, судя по наличию папки build - да

Comment: @КамиловТимур, на самом деле, чтобы понять, какие файлы нужно отправить на сервер, надо смотреть конфигурацию webpack

Comment: @Bleser нет пока не вызывал команду npm build. А что она дает?

Comment: @Bleser вот только сейчас ее вызвал.. Что мне дальше делать?

Comment: @Камилов Тимур поидее должна появится папка `dist`, но у вас ее видимо заменяет `build`. В этой паке должен находит один или несколько `*.js` файлов которые нужно подключить в `index.html`, если это еще не сделано, тогда Вам нужно перенести на сервер `index.html, build, static`. Вы можете попробовать без запуска dev - сервера открыть в браузере `index.html` и посмотреть работает ли то что вы написали.

Comment: т.е остальные файлы по идее можно удалить? package.json, node_modules и т.д

Comment: @Камилов Тимур Они необходимы для дальнейшей разработки. В package.json хранятся списки зависимостей, запускаемые скрипты и иные настройки. В node_modules находятся пакеты которые были скачены через `npm`. Лучше просто скопировать нужные файлы в другой каталог и уже там экспериментировать.

Comment: Не работает при добавление *.js файлов в index.html. Что делать?

Comment: даже Github Pages не принимает. Хотя скинул я туда все что есть ((( Помогите плиз ((

Comment: @КамиловТимур Если есть возможность выложите ваш код на github. Еще просьба при ответе добавлять '@ник' иначе не видно уведомлений.